# Clone managed entity with @OneToMany JPA mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, clone, one-to-many

Given I have 3 JPA entities with @OneToMany bidirectional mappings and `MyEntity` is root level entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myEntity", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities = new LinkedList<>();

}

@Entity
public class OtherEntity extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @ManyToOne
    private MyEntity myEntity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "otherEntity", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<YetAnotherEntity> yetAnotherEntities = new LinkedList<>();

}

@Entity
public class YetAnotherEntity extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @ManyToOne
    private OtherEntity otherEntity;

}
```

I'd like to create a copy of `MyEntity`, remove few `OtherEntity`ies based on filtering criteria and than serialize it to `OutputStream` using Jackson (export it)

How can I achieve it?

I was trying to use:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

and call: `em.detach(myEntity);`, but this results in `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to session`

EDIT:
Adding export service method:

```
@Override
public void export(MyEntity myEntity, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

    em.detach(myEntity);

    MyEntity myEntityToBeExported = new MyEntity();
    // filter out OtherEntities which we don't want to export
    List<OtherEntity> filteredOtherEntities = myEntity.getOtherEntities().stream()
            .filter(otherEntity -> ...)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    myEntityToBeExported.addOtherEntities(filteredOtherEntities);

    ObjectMapper mapper = mapperProvider.mapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, myEntityToBeExported);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code which uses `em.detach()`. Note that trying to access `MyEntity.otherEntities` or `OtherEntity.yetAnotherEntities` on a detached entity will result in lazy initialization exceptions unless you initialize the collections explicitly before detaching.

Comment: I added `export` method which `call em.detach()`

Comment: How do you obtain the reference to `myEntity`? Is it indeed possible that `export()` is getting called from another thread? It seems as though you are trying to detach `myEntity` from an entity manager different from the one that was used to retrieve it

Comment: It is actually done behind the scenes by `DomainClassConverter` from Spring Data: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic
`export` service method is called from `Controller` method: 
`void exportMerchant(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") MyEntity myEntity) {...}`

Comment: If your controller is not transactional, chances are `myEntity` is already detached. However, for the same reason, the issue from my first comment still persists. I can think of a couple of workarounds (you could, for example, make the 'many' side of the two associations eagerly fetched), but your safest bet is to pass the id to the service instead, load the entity from the session, initialize the collections, *and then* detach it. Note that for loading the associations, you will need a transaction.

Comment: Also note that changes to the *inverse* side of an association (i.e. the one with `mappedBy` defined) are ignored by jpa, so detaching the entity is not strictly required in your case. However, you might want to serialize the entity outside a transaction for performance reasons, in which case the entity will become detached automatically